# 'release' flavor files not visible in 'Android' tree pane

Tags: android, android-studio

I want some classes to have two flavors - 'release' and 'debug'.

Have created two corresponding directories under project `app/src/`, so as a result I have 3 directories - `main` (for common to both flavors sources), `release` and `debug`.

In `buildType` section inside `build.gradle` there is `release` variant.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.bottomnav"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see in files tree pane all the source sets. But now `release` is missed.

[image]

How can I make `release` sources visible, like `debug`, `test` and `androidTest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because only the directories linked to your current build type and flavor are displayed. If you select "release" as build variant for your app in the Build Variants tab, the "release" directory will appear and the "debug" one will disappear.

[image]

Bear in mind that Build types and Flavors are two different things. According to what you've posted, you only have defined build types in your gradle file.
See more info in the doc: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create  `release` folder and put classes specific to this flavor inside it. Then choose proper BuildVariant to build desired flavor/buildType